# Templates delete in C++ when List<List<X>>

Tags: c++, list, templates, generics, delete-operator

I am trying to develop a generic List with templates. This list is compound by a Pointer array T* , an integer for getting the number of elements and some methods( find, contains...) It´s important to say that I cannot use std::library.

My problem comes when I am working with a `List<List<int> >` for instance.

One of the methods make a resizing of the `T*` pointer array, So when I have this `List<List>>`I create an auxpointer of a bigger size than `T*` and copying `T` content to auxpointer with a `memcpy`. The inner Pointers  (`list.T.T`) are copied as pointers too, not memory duplicated, so when I delete the `T*` pointer and reasign `T=auxpointer`.  I have already lost the data of that pointers in my `new T`.

```
template <typename T>
void CGenericList<T>::resize()
{
    T* auxPointer = new T[this->maxElements*2];
    memcpy (auxPointer,this->pointer,this->maxElements*sizeof(T));
    delete[] this->pointer;     
    this->pointer=auxPointer;
    this->maxElements=2*this->maxElements;
}

template<class T>
class CGenericList
{
public:
    T* pointer;
    int N;
    int maxElements;

    CGenericList();
    CGenericList(int);
    ~CGenericList();
    void resize();  
}
```

Can anyone give me any tips for doing it?

Comment: Since you described what the problem is, why don't you prefer copying the elements from old array to new array and then destruct the old array ?

Comment: because with memcpy it is suposed to be faster, and speed is a critical point of algorithm

Comment: If you want to resize the memory being pointed to by this->pointer then why not realloc the memory. That should preserve the data inside or is realloc slower than memcpy?

Comment: I have not considered realloc at all, but it could be a good option. I am trying it. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Well, `memcpy` is just totally the wrong approach in C++, ever. Maybe `std::copy` will give you more success?

Comment: `memcpy` is just wrong in C++ (won't work for non-POD `T`); `std::copy` should be just as fast.  `realloc` won't mix with `new` and `delete`.  Why can't you use the `std` library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted shows some problems.

```
T* auxPointer = new T[this->maxElements*2];
```

here you allocate a new array of maxElements*2 - and call the default constructor.
Which in your case probably initialises all Listelements.

```
memcpy (auxPointer,this->pointer,this->maxElements*sizeof(T));
```

After that you copy the content of your old array to the memory area of the newly allocated memory. This overwrites the pointers to the just created Listelements with the ones from the old array -> memory leak.

```
delete[] this->pointer;
```

Then you delete the array, this calls the destructors of all elements.
Which hopefully will delete their content and free their memory.

```
this->pointer=auxPointer;
```

Finally you reassign the newly created array. The pointers in the list point to the old listselements and point to not allocated memory anymore (because of the call to the destructor via delete[]).

A solution would be to implement an copy constructor for your list and call it for all
elements in your array. (DeepCopy) And of course an assignment operator, i almost forgot ;)

```
CGenericList(const CGenericList<T>& copy);
CGenericList<T>& operator= (const CGenericList<T>& rhs)
```

Probably somethig like this - be aware that this is "asis" and definitely not exceptionsafe ;)

```
template<class T>
class CGenericList
{
public:
    T* pointer;
    int N;
    int maxElements;

    CGenericList();
    CGenericList( const CGenericList<T>& copy );
    CGenericList<T>& operator=(const CGenericList<T>& rhs);
    CGenericList(int);
    ~CGenericList();
    void resize();
};

template <typename T>
void CGenericList<T>::resize()
{
    T* auxPointer = new T[this->maxElements*2];
    for(int i=0; i < this->maxElements; i++)
    {
        auxPointer[i] = this->pointer[i];
    }
    delete[] this->pointer;
    this->pointer = auxPointer;
    this->maxElements = this->maxElements*2;
}

template <typename T>
CGenericList<T>::CGenericList()
    :N(0)
    ,maxElements(0)
{
    this->pointer = new T[1];
}

template <typename T>
CGenericList<T>::CGenericList(const CGenericList<T>& copy)
    :N(copy.N)
    ,maxElements(copy.maxElements)
{
    T* temp = new T[copy.maxElements];
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++ )
    {
        temp[i] = copy.pointer[i];
    }
    this->pointer = temp;
}

template <typename T>
CGenericList<T>& CGenericList<T>::operator=(const CGenericList<T>& rhs)
{
    if( this != &rhs )
    {
        delete[] this->pointer;
        this->pointer = new T[rhs.maxElements];
        for(int i=0; i<rhs.maxElements; i++)
        {
            this->pointer[i] = rhs.pointer[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}


template <typename T>
CGenericList<T>::CGenericList(int size)
    :N(0)
    ,maxElements(size)
{
    this->pointer = new T[size];
}

template <typename T>
CGenericList<T>::~CGenericList()
{
    delete[] this->pointer;
}


int main(int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[])
{
    CGenericList<CGenericList<int> > list;
    list.resize();

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't like to use stl you can have a look at [stlport](http://stlport.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `resize` is not exception safe. You are first deleting the existing array and then allocating memory for a different size and then assigning auxPointer.
Coming to the problem you are having, check if the below approach helps.

```
T* auxPointer = new T[this->maxElements*2];       
for ( int i =0; i < this->maxElements; ++i)
   std::swap(auxPointer[i], pointer[i]);

delete[] this->pointer;    
this->pointer = auxPointer;  
this->maxElements=2*this->maxElements;
```

Comment: Why `swap` rather than `copy`?  Also, this is not exception-safe either (there's a potential for memory leak).

Comment: How is this not exception safe ? Actually, there is a memory leak in Pau's resize().

Comment: copy the pointers to auxPointer and then delete this->pointer. Is this not a problem ?

Comment: If any of the copying/swapping throws an exception, then the stack will unwind without deleting the memory you just allocated.